# reset edittext while switching between tabs in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am using tabs in my application . Each tab is pointing to 3 different activities.

```
    TabHost host=getTabHost();
    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("one")
.setIndicator("Register")
.setContent(new Intent(this, Register.class)));
host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("two")
.setIndicator("View")
.setContent(new Intent(this, View.class)));
host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("three")
.setIndicator("Summary")
.setContent(new Intent(this, Summary.class)));
```

There is a `textview result` in View class which i am setting after a button click.
My question is when i am switching to another tab and coming back to that tab(View) `textview result` is still set i want it to be blank , when i switch between tabs. 
Can any one help me out in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding onResume() of your tab activity. You can reset textview to blank there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming View is an Activity. If so, you just need to reset the TextView in the onResume method of the View class.